# Replace substring in one column with value from another column in same row

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database with two columns, `id` and `file`:

```
id    file
1     /img/333.PNG
2     /img/452645.jpg
3     /img/1.gif
```

The `file`s are all the same path (`/img/`), a number, and a graphics file extension, some in lower (`.png`), some in upper case (`.JPEG`).

#### How can I replace the path and numeric part of `file` with the `id` (from the same row)?

The result for the above sample should look like:

```
id    file
1     1.PNG
2     2.jpg
3     3.gif
```

Notes:

- I don't want to rename the actual files, just the database entries.
- I want to rename `file` in all rows using only one query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
UPDATE table SET file = CONCAT(id, '.', RIGHT(file, 3));
```

To accommodate JPEG extension locate position of dot.

```
UPDATE table SET file = CONCAT(id, SUBSTRING(file, POSITION('.' IN file)));
```